# IIS 10 on Windows server 2016 error 503 9 queuefull

Tags: server, iis-10

I have a situation where I can't find helpful information on Google, and don't know how to solve it.

I have 2 servers. Server A handles IIS and server B handles SQL:

- Server A running Windows server 2016, IIS 10
- Server B running Windows server 2012, IIS 8

I use the internal IP address of server B in the connection string. The internal network is very fast, 1Gbps

Server A is stronger than server B. When I have few hundred users, server A starts emitting the error:

> 503 9 queuefull .net+v4.5

I found it on "C:\Windows\system32\logfiles\HTTPERR".

Then I let the server B handle both IIS and SQL.
The connection string still uses the internal IP of server B. And now, on server B, which is not as powerful as server A, I don't have any problems.

What should I do to analyze and solve the issue on server A?